# Meaning of 指摘しない程度に

Tags: meaning

I do not understand this 「指摘しない程度に」 .

It appears in advertisements and also I received a letter, an answer to my Q and I just don't get it:

> これで本人が力みもなくちゃんと演奏出来るのであれば、わざわざ指摘しない程度にきちんと構えられていますよ！

Comment: It would probably be faster if I just answered rather than leaving a comment since it is an easy question, but how is this question any better than the other "translation" questions that get closed?

Comment: @非回答者 The question has only been around for 40 minutes or so. It takes time for close voters to show up and vote to close a question. You have more than enough reputation to cast close votes; if you think this should be closed because it is a translation request, you can do so.

Comment: On the flip side, if you think this question is OK to answer, by all means go ahead and do so.

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be immediately closed because where and why OP got stuck is specific and almost self-explanatory. However, I have difficulty figuring out what is said here with 100% confidence. Is this a real ad? And what's this ad for, maybe a wearable device or something to correct the posture of musicians?

Answer (score 3):

To be blunt, this was probably written by someone with poor writing skills. I would correct it at least to:

> これで本人が、力みもなくちゃんと演奏出来るのであれば、わざわざ指摘する必要のない程度にきちんと構えられていますよ！

This'd still not be particularly well written.

I think the intention is better expressed e.g. like this:

> 本人がこれで力みもなく演奏出来るのであれば、ある程度きちんと構えられていると思うので、わざわざ指摘する必要はないかと思います